# How to insert/remove/edit rows in QAbstractListModel?

Tags: c++, qt, model, qml

So, I had a QAbstractList model - `ContactBookModel`. The model elements are represented by the `Contact` class, which contains the constructor and the `name` and `number` fields.

It worked, but only view, I couldn't edit it.

Then I added this method:

```
Q_INVOKABLE bool add(const QString& name, const QString& number);
```

If you need implementation:

```
bool ContactBookModel::add(const QString& name, const QString& number)
{
    try
    {
        if(name.isEmpty() || number.isEmpty())
        {
            return false;
        }
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
        contacts.append(Contact(name, number));
        endInsertRows();
        return true;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works, I call this method from QML and pass 2 strings from `TextFields` as parameters.

But documentation said I need reimplement `insertRow()` method for it.

Ok, it should be looks like this:

```
bool ContactBookModel::insertRow(int row, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())
{
   beginInsertRows(parent, row, row+1);
   contacts.append(/*what should be here?*/); //contacts is a private field in a ContactBookModel. They have got a QList<Contact> type. 
   endInsertRows();
}
```

1) As you can see, when I used add, I construct Contact in method, using two fields for it. How to do it with `insertRow()`? Where to get (construct) `Contact`?

2) How to delete a contact? Documentation said I should reimplement `removeRow()`. How to use it in QML?

3) How to edit contact from QML?

Full project code here:
https://github.com/bogdasar1985/ContactBook

Comment: Did you get answers to all the questions you have asked in the post ? If yes, please share the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want a way to edit the elements in the model.
So you have to enable the clickability of the deletegates. Your current code doesn't offer that, so add a `mousearea` and emit a `signal` when clicked on the element.

next you can take the `currentIndex` name and number values and use it in your `addWindow` or whatever window you want.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: contact
    width: parent.width
    height: 30

    signal clicked()

Rectangle {
    id: mainRect
    anchors.fill: parent
    border.color: "black"
    visible: true
    Text {
        id: nameText
        text: name
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 4
    }
    Text {
        id: numberText
        text: number
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 4
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: rectMousearea
        anchors.fill: mainRect
        hoverEnabled: true
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
        onClicked: contact.clicked()
    }
}
}
```

and then in the `Listview` delegate

```
            delegate: Contact{
                onClicked: {
                    addwindow.name = model.name
                    addwindow.number = model.number
                    addwindow.show()
                }
            }
```

add two aliases in the beginning of `addWindow.qml`

```
Window {
    id: addwindow
    visible: false
    width: 320
    height: 320
    title: qsTr("Add contact")

    property alias name: nameField.text
    property alias number: numberField.text
```

remember to return in `add` method when the `name` and `number` values are same. or you can handle that from qml also.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: And what this code should do? At the moment this code realize functional what I already have. Specify, what this code does?

Comment: It works, thanks! But when I started edit contact, change nothing and push "Confirm" the same contact is inserted at the end. But, what more important is to understand, C++ methods. And how to remove row?

Comment: to make the change appear, you should use the `notify signal` in your Q_PROPERTY of `name` and `number`. So when you set the edited values in your delegate they will trigger the change signals and you automatically will have new values.

Comment: but to edit contact, we need to change content of a `QList<Contact> contacts`. It will happen?